# Como alterar em tempo de execução o conteúdo de uma qLabel?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt-4

Boa tarde pessoal! Eu preciso que cada linha de qLinedit seja numerada em ordem crescente do 1 até o 24, criei uma qLabel para isso, mas não sei como fazer com que ela altere a numeração conforme cada linha, só consegui imprimir um monte de [i] como mostra a imagem[[aqui][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EO53t.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EO53t.png). O que posso fazer?

```
    self.ql_coords = {}
    self.num = {}
    #nós

    lo_nodes = qg.QGridLayout()
    #no = qg.Qlabel('Node')
    x = qg.QLabel('x:')
    y = qg.QLabel('y:')
    z = qg.QLabel('z:')

    for i in range(0,24):
        self.num[str(i+1)+str(0)] = qg.QLabel('[i]') #cria a qlabel
        lo_nodes.addWidget(self.num[str(i+1)+str(0)], i+1, 0) #adiciona a qlabel ao layout
        for j in range(1,4):
            self.ql_coords[str(i)+str(j)] = qg.QLineEdit() #cria as qlineedits
            lo_nodes.addWidget(self.ql_coords[str(i)+str(j)], i+1, j) #adiciona as qlineedits ao layout
            lo_nodes.addWidget(x, 0, 1) 
            lo_nodes.addWidget(y, 0 ,2) 
            lo_nodes.addWidget(z, 0, 3)
```

Comment: Alterar texto de um QLabel em tempo de execução é completamente diferente de criar o QLabel em tempo de execução, seria bom esclarecer. Se quer criar, basta passar a string na criação (que parece ser o seu caso, mas você está passando uma string fixa em vez de usar a variavel). Se quer alterar (ou seja, mudar um QLabel existente), tem que chamar o método .setText

Answer (score 0):

O parâmetro passado no `QLabel` é o que será exibido. Logo, se você quer que número sejam exibidos, é necessário passar esse número como parâmetro em forma de `string`. O seu código pode ser alterado das seguintes formas:

Se estiver usando Python 2:

```
self.num[str(i+1)+str(0)] = qg.QLabel('[%d]' % i+1) #cria a qlabel
```

Se estiver usando Python 3:

```
self.num[str(i+1)+str(0)] = qg.QLabel('[{}]'.format(i+1)) #cria a qlabel
```

Se estiver usando Python 3.6+:

```
self.num[str(i+1)+str(0)] = qg.QLabel(f'[{i+1}]') #cria a qlabel
```

Eu não sei se os `[]` são necessários na sua exibição. Mas para as funções acima eles não são obrigatórios.